# How does Kibana know the supported aggregations of an (Elasticsearch) data type?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am working on a platform that integrates Elasticsearch into itself.
Some part of this software is basically a kind of front-end for Elasticsearch.

Kibana somehow knows which aggregations a specific Elasticsearch data type supports.
I have examined the HTTP requests sent by Kibana, but I could not find where that information originates. (Maybe, I was not thorough.)

So, my question is:
How does Kibana determine which aggregations an Elasticsearch data type supports?
Is it possible to get that via the Elasticsearch API, or was it hard-coded on the client-side (in Kibana)?

Example:
[image: Kibana]

Answer (score 0):

Kibana uses [index patterns](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/index-patterns.html) as a key concept. It knows the linked indices and the underlying field structure (index mapping) of those indices. Based on these index patterns Kibana can determine which [aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/supported-aggregations.html) are compatible with a specific field.

For example, the [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.9/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) works on fields of type [keyword](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html) or other [data types](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-types.html) suitable for [bucket aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/supported-aggregations.html#visualize-bucket-aggregations). For text fields, you´ll need to enable fielddata to use the terms aggregation.

If you are missing an aggregation for a specific field, check if using a [multi-field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-types.html#_multi_fields) with a different data type will solve it. Afterward, update the index pattern in kibana and you´ll be able to aggregate on the new [multi-field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although I already knew that.

What I'd like to know is how could I request the list of supported aggregations of an Elasticsearch data type so that I can use that list in my application.

I can imagine two ways how that gets handled currently: 
1. The supported aggregations of Elasticsearch data types can get requested via the Elasticsearch API.
2. The list of the supported aggregations of an ES data type is hard-coded on the front-end (Kibana).